# Python - Read Dictionary of Lists from CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to read a dictionary of List from a CSV file. 
I'm trying to access to data-structure like:

```
dbfree = {u'keyname': [u'x', 'y', 'z']}
```

These data structures are stored in a CSV file with this code:

```
for key, val in dbfree.items():
     w.writerow([key, val])
```

I read the CSV in this way:

```
dbproj = {}
for key, val in unicodecsv.reader(open(filename)):
    dbproj[key] = val
```

But the output is this:

```
{u'key name': u"[u'x', 'y', 'z']"
```

How can I correctly retrieve the full dictionary of lists from my CSV file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote the *`repr()`* output of the nested list here:

```
for key, val in dbfree.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

here `val` is `[u'x', 'y', 'z']`; to store that in one column the `csv` file simply writes the result of `repr(val)`.

You can decode that string to a Python object again with the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

dbproj = {}
for key, val in unicodecsv.reader(open(filename)):
    dbproj[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)
```

`ast.literal_eval()` interprets the input as a Python expression, but limited to *literals*, Python syntax that defines objects such as dictionaries, lists, tuples, sets and strings, numbers, booleans and `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to de-serialize the value, you can use `json` module:

```
import json

 for key, val in dbfree.items():
      w.writerow([key, json.dumps(val)])
```

for reading:

```
dbproj = {}
for key, val in unicodecsv.reader(open(filename)):
    dbproj[key] = json.loads(val)
```