# Reading data from Excel into a Python dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv

I have a data set in an excel file with the following structure

```
       col1   col2   col3   col4
              a1      a2     a3
row2  label  100     200    300
row3  label  300     400    500
```

I would like to parse the data such that the following dictionary is created:

```
{'a1': [100, 300], 'a2': [200, 400], 'a3': [300, 500]}
```

I have looked at using csv.writer and pandas. I couldn't see how it was possible with the former (I consulted this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808449/python-read-dictionary-of-lists-from-csv)) so I tried the latter as follows:

```
xls = ExcelFile('1.xlsx') 
df = xls.parse
dict = df.to_dict()
```

Here's what I obtained:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 'label', 1: 'label'}, 'a1': {0: 100, 1: 300}, 'a2': {0: 200, 1: 400}, 'a3': {0: 300, 1: 500}}
```

Can I change nested dictionaries to lists (or tuples, for that matter) and remove the index numbers? That would get me close to what I'm seeking, I think. Alternatively, perhaps I need a mutli-step process. I appreciate I could store the data in json and it would be a lot easier but it's constantly being manually updated and json is not very suitable in that respect.

Comment: In the excel spreadsheet they are just individual columns, as per col1, col2 etc. Tabs and or commas would apply to some sort of text file, would they not (apologies if I've misunderstood your question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is saved in a csv file in the format you mentioned above, this will do what you want:

```
qwe = pd.read_csv(file_path).to_dict('list')
qwe.pop('Unnamed: 0')
qwe
```

Output:

```
{'a1': [100, 300], 'a2': [200, 400], 'a3': [300, 500]}
```

Comment: I was just working on a really ugly solution involved iterating through each row and excluding stuff. This is exactly what I was looking for!!